# Recover/import ZFS pool from single old mirror

Tags: linux, data-recovery, zfs

I made a couple serious errors dealing with my ZFS pools the other day (while misreading some online advice in fixing an error) and accidentally "created over" an existing 2-drive mirrored pool named `backup`.  (Yes, I used the `-f` option after it complained.  And now I know never to do this again.)

In any case, I happen to have taken out a 3rd mirrored drive from the same pool a few months back, as it was getting old and I didn't want to wait for it to start to fail.  So, I thought that I could swap this drive in and use it to restore the pool.  (I'd just be missing out on the past few months of backups, which is mostly what this pool is used for.)

However, I don't seem to be able to import the pool with this single old drive.  At first, I thought it might have had to do with the name conflict with the new `backup` pool I accidentally created (and then destroyed).  But even when trying to import via GUID, I get nothing.

Here's the output from zdb -l /dev/sdb1 (which is the third drive)

```
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'backup'
    state: 0
    txg: 0
    pool_guid: 3936176493905234028
    errata: 0
    hostid: 8323329
    hostname: [omitted]
    top_guid: 14695910886267065742
    guid: 17986383713788026938
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'mirror'
        id: 0
        guid: 14695910886267065742
        whole_disk: 0
        metaslab_array: 34
        metaslab_shift: 33
        ashift: 12
        asize: 1000197324800
        is_log: 0
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 17914838236907067293
            path: '/dev/sdd1'
            whole_disk: 0
            DTL: 143
            create_txg: 4
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 17986383713788026938
            path: '/dev/sdb1'
            whole_disk: 0
            DTL: 141
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 1683783279473519399
            path: '/dev/sdc1'
            whole_disk: 0
            DTL: 145
            create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    create_txg: 0
    labels = 0 1 2 3
```

Thus, the drive and pool data on the drive seem to be intact, according to zdb.  However, importing the pool (even with `-f` and/or `-F`) just gets an "cannot import... no such pool available" error.  I tried using the various GUIDs in the above info too (since I wasn't sure with GUID was the relevant one), but none of those commands (e.g., `zpool import 3936176493905234028`) gets anything other than the "no such pool available" message.

I have installed a new version of my Linux OS since I removed that drive, so I thought using the old `zpool.cache` file I managed to recover from the old OS might do something.  But the command  `zpool import -c zpool.cache` just gives:

```
  pool: backup
     id: 3936176493905234028
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

    backup      UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      mirror-0  UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        sdd1    FAULTED  corrupted data
        sdc1    FAULTED  corrupted data
```

Which is somewhat to be expected. Those are the two disks where the pool was overwritten by my create command. However, sdb1 isn't listed as a potential drive there -- probably because I removed it from the pool after I took the disk out. Nevertheless, I think I have an intact copy of old mirrored data on sdb1, and zdb agrees. Why won't it import?

Any suggestions on what else to try?  Other diagnostic commands to run?

---

Note: I tried [asking about this over at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/1000418/557257) (see link for more details about my situation), but I didn't get any feedback and realized the specific Linux implementation may be important in figuring out how to resolve this.  I would sincerely appreciate any advice or suggestions.

---

**UPDATE:** I think I may have found the problem.  I thought that I had removed the spare drive before I had issued a `detach` command.  And the fact that I was still seeing label information (when other online sources seem to indicate `detach` destroys the pool metadata) seemed to confirm that.  I note that I'm able to simply type `zdb -l backup` and get label info (and get uberblock info with `-u`), so zfs seems to see the pool even without explicitly pointing to the device.  It just doesn't want to import it for some reason.

However, I'm no longer certain about the `detach` status.  I came upon [this old thread](https://thr3ads.net/zfs-discuss/2008/04/351635-recovering-data-from-a-dettach-mirrored-vdev) about recovering a ZFS pool from a detached mirror, and it makes a cryptic reference to `txg` having a value of zero.  There are also references elsewhere to uberblocks being zeroed out upon a `detach`.

Well, the uberblock to my `backup` pool does list `txg = 0` (while an active zpool I have elsewhere has large numbers in this field, not zero).  And while there is an existing uberblock, there's only one, with the others on `backup` listed as "invalid."  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find much documentation of anything coming out of `zdb` easily available online.

I assume that means the spare third drive was detached?  Can anyone confirm my interpretation?  However, if the drive data is otherwise intact, is there any way to recover from it?  While [some advice online](https://serverfault.com/q/641136) suggests a detached mirror is unrecoverable without resilvering, the thread I linked above has code for Solaris that seems to do a rather simple function to trick the label into thinking the uberblock is fine.  Further poking around found me an [updated Solaris version of this utility](https://github.com/bnjf/labelfix) from only three years ago.

Assuming my understanding is correct and that my third mirror was detached, can I attempt a similar uberblock label fix in Linux?  Is my only option to attempt to rewrite the Solaris code so that it ports to Linux?  (I'm not sure I'm up to that.)

Honestly, given multiple references to scenarios like this online, I'm surprised at the lack of reasonable data recovery tools for ZFS.  It seems [there are finally some options](https://www.delphix.com/blog/openzfs-pool-import-recovery) for basic data recovery for common problems (including a possibility for recovering a pool that was written over by a `create` command; this doesn't appear to be likely to work for me), but other than this one-off script for Solaris, I don't see anything for dealing with detached devices.  It's very frustrating to realize that there are at least a dozen reasons why ZFS pools may fail to import (sometimes for trivial things that could be easily recoverable), and little in the way of troubleshooting, proper error codes, or documentation.

Again, any help, thoughts, or suggestions would be appreciated.  **Even if someone could recommend a better place to ask about this, I'd really appreciate it.**

**UPDATE2:** It's also possible the device was merely put `offline` as I think it was.  I've read various threads that say offline devices can end up unimportable as single mirrors too.  And as the metadata and zdb output is poorly documented for ZFS, I really don't know how to determine what the uberblock and label data mean without reading through thousands of lines of source code.

Comment: check logs in your syslog to see what you have done, maybe it will help you find what commands you have executed

Comment: @αғsнιη - Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, my syslog files don't go back to when I removed the third drive.  (I probably have archived versions of old log files -- except they are on the backup volumes I'm actually trying to access.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm close and think I've found a path to recovery.  Since I haven't received advice from others, I'll post what I've learned so far.

**Summary:**

- There is an unmaintained, not-officially-supported `labelfix` utility for fixing labels on certain kinds of corrupted (and offline/detached) ZFS volumes, which can be used to make an unimportable pool importable.
- Before doing anything, be sure to clone the old spare devices and only work on the clones.
- If you have a situation as described in the question with two pools of the same name (due to a mistaken `create` or other error), make sure only devices are plugged in with the specific pool you want to recover.
- Also, remove any devices that may have ever been associated with the pool you want to recover but which are faulted.  (That applies even if you think you've completely destroyed any other pools and disassociated these devices.  The recovery tools will try to piece together fragments of old pools, and may read old labels/uberblocks to combine devices and data in unpredictable ways.)

---

**More details:**

There appears to be a way to recover offline and detached drives from zpools on Linux.  A user jjwhitney created a [port of the labelfix utility](https://gist.github.com/jjwhitney/baaa63144da89726e482) I mentioned in the question, originally written by Jeff Bonwick (the inventor of ZFS) [nearly 12 years ago](https://thr3ads.net/zfs-discuss/2008/04/351635-recovering-data-from-a-dettach-mirrored-vdev).  For reasons I cannot fathom, this utility has not been incorporated into ZFS builds, even though it would allow recovery of data for intact pools when an import fails for a number of reasons due to invalid labels.  (Some discussion on the issue [here](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/4187).)

(Sidenote: One thing this process has led me to realize is that ZFS recovery tools are severely lacking, and no one should be using this filesystem for *anything* without complete backups of data running all the time.  And don't depend on that old mirrored drive sitting in your closet to be a last-chance backup unless you're sure it's importable.  ZFS is apparently great at maintaining data integrity when ZFS cooperates, but incredibly fragile.  And when it breaks -- or you do something minor but stupid -- your data can simply all be inaccessible and unreadable, even if intact.)

In any case, the labelfix utility hasn't been updated in 5 years, so it doesn't compile with modern ZFS library files.  Luckily, I had the original OS version still installed and could boot to that, then download an old [ZFS on Linux](https://zfsonlinux.org/) source tarball and use that to get the appropriate ZFS libraries and build environment on a system where it all still works.  (I started tweaking the labelfix utility to try to work with modern ZFS libraries, but that seemed a little dangerous given how little I understand about all the internals I'd need to fix to correspond to the current codebase.  Easier to just build it on an old version.)

And lo, `labelfix` immediately and easily rewrote the label on my device to something that `zpool import` could at least interpret!

I should say that I used `ddrescue` to copy the whole thing from the original drive before attempting any of this.  And I would highly recommend that, as it's possible to make mistakes, as I did.  The original pool I accidentally wrote over was named `backup`, so `zdb` started seeing multiple versions of the different `backup` pools and couldn't figure out why all the metadata didn't match.  I had to tweak `vdev_validate_skip=1` in the ZFS kernel module to get the pool to import, but that then just imported the *newer* `backup` pool (not the one I wanted).  Note that this happened even though I specified the exact path to the drive I wanted to `import` from: when forcing imports with this method, it seemed to completely ignore my specification and draw on a completely different configuration from a device that wasn't listed in the command.

Luckily, I had made another clone of the drive, so I could attempt another run.  However, `labelfix` also is smart and seems to read the current drive configuration, so it picked up on the fact that I had two old drives with "corrupted data" from the first `backup` pool.  The corruption unfortunately meant that the "fixed" label listed the pool not only as `DEGRADED` but also `FAULTED` and thus un-`import`-able.

At this point I realized I simply had to unplug all the old drives and work without them in the system at all to avoid corrupting recovery attempts. 
 Unfortunately, `labelfix` only seems to fix things once, so I am now on to clone #3 of this drive (which is currently copying from my first backup clone).  Once that cloning process finishes, I'll run `labelfix` without any of the other old drives present, and hopefully I'll get a `DEGRADED` pool that I can then `import`.

Comment: I just wanted to note for anyone that happens upon this question in the future that although the labelfix utility did seem to do something in terms of what zdb and zpool import commands could see, I was never able to successfully import the drive.  However, a ZFS recovery utility for ~$50 easily found all the files quickly and painlessly.  All data seems to be intact and uncorrupted.  Too bad there's no basic functionality built into ZFS to get access to intact and uncorrupted data when import fails.

Comment: Hi @Athanasius I am desperate to find a recovery solution myself. What tool did you buy for $50 that solved it for you?

Comment: @JWM: I ended up using UFS Explorer Recovery.  It does have some limitations -- I had a lot of hardlinked files in a backup pool and wasn't able to recover the links, so those files were somewhat useless.  I think I lost one or two other files I wasn't able to recover cleanly for whatever reason, but the rest of the disk (aside from hardlinks) was fine.